# Is it possible to develop apps on Google Plus?

Tags: facebook, api, google-plus, facebook-canvas

Is it possible to create applications on Google Plus in the same manner as Facebook?

In other words, "Apps on Facebook are web apps that are loaded in the context of Facebook in what we refer to as a Canvas Page". Does a similar API exist for google plus? 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No

Slightly longer answer: There are some vendors who have access to a Game API, which appears to work very similarly to Facebook's API, but this API isn't public yet, and there is no clear indication how to get access. There is also the Google+ Hangout API, which is public, that lets you write applications that run inside a hangout. This works similarly to how a Facebook app works, but are limited to working inside a hangout only.

Definitive answer: https://developers.google.com/+/ contains references to all the public APIs that work with Google+, including the Hangout API.